# Creating an HTML Request Form

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I'm trying to create this html form but I'm having problems especially with resizing the Fieldset and legend. I am new to programming and practising on some html forms. I want it that when the window is resized, the form should take the size of the window but not to displace the contents. With my code below, the input fields and check boxes are always displaced and not in line when window is resized. I would be happy if anyone can help me out.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bestell.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend id="one">
        <img src="http://www.myhomematic.de/images/manufacturers/mediola-
logo-trans.png" class="image">
    </legend>
    <h1>Bestellantrag</h1>
    <p>(für Investitionsgüter über € 400)</p>
    <label for="antragssteller" class="">Antragssteller:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="imput">
    <!--<p>Name</p>-->
    <label for="abteilung" class="abteilung_space">Abteilung:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="begin1"> R&D
    <input type="checkbox" class="begin1"> Marketing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="begin21"> Operation
    <input type="checkbox" class="begin22"> Vertrieb<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="begin3"> Admin
</fieldset><br><br>
<div>
    <label for="Anschaffungswert">Anschaffungswert:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="none">
    <label for="Zeitpunkt" class="even">Zeitpunkt:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="none"><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="investitionsart"
class="investion">Investitionsart:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one"/> 
Neuinvestition
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one"/> 
Projekt
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one"/> 
 Testequipment<br><br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="intern" class="somethin">Intern:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one1"/> 
Ersatzbeschaffung
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one11"/>
veraltet
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one12"/> 
defekt<br><br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="Bestellung">Bestellung:</label>
     <input type="text" value="" class="now1"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" class="odd"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" class="odd"><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="Begründung">Begründung:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="now"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" class="odd"><br>
    <input type="text" value="" class="odd"><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="erfolgt">Bestellung erfolgt bei:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="different"><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="bestellung" class="definite">Bestellung:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one2"> 
genehmigt
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="one2"> 
abgelehnt<br><br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="datum">Datum:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="">
    <label for="Unterschrift" class="even2">Unterschrift:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class=""><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="abgelehnt">Begründung wenn abgelehnt:</label>
    <input type="text" class="last" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please don't take particular care of my class names, I just name them so I could style them...Any advice on becoming a good programmer are greatly welcomed

The Styling

```
body{
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;
}
.fieldset{
display:inline;
border: solid 1px black;
}
label{
text-align: center;
}
h1{
letter-spacing: 4px;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: inherit;
margin-right: 600px;
}
p{
margin-right: 610px;
}
input[type="text"]{
width: 320px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
transition: 0.3s;
display: inline;
height: 19px;
margin-top: 13px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
margin-top: 15px;
text-align: center;
}
legend{
width: 262px;
margin-left: 650px;
}
.image{
width: 300px;
}
.odd{
margin-left: 125px;
width: 790px !important;
}
.even{
margin-left: 40px;
}
.none{
margin-left: 0px;
}
.even2{
margin-left: 120px;
}
.last{
width: 400px !important;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.begin1{
margin-left: 60px;
}
.begin2{
margin-left: 300px;
}
.begin21{
margin-left: 612px;
}
.begin22{
margin-left: 22px;
}
.begin3{
margin-left: 485px;
}
.one{
margin-left: 133px;
}
.one1{
 margin-left: 190px;
}
.one11{
margin-left: 101px;
}
.one12{
margin-left: 132px;
}
.last{
width: 690px !important;
}
.different{
width: 743px !important;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.now{
width: 789px !important;
margin-left: 29px;
}
.now1{
width: 790px !important;
margin-left: 39px;
}
.one2{
margin-left: 158px;
}
.abteilung_space{
margin-left: 39px;
}
.imput{
margin-left: 20px;
}
.investion{
margin-left: 125px;
}
.definite{
margin-left: 121px;
}
.somethin{
margin-left: 63px;
}
```

[image: At the end I should get something like this]

UPDATE:

Adding a jsfiddle to help visualize the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/jsallans/ok2qf1jo/

Comment: As for my understanding, you want a fluid form of yours that won't look ugly when the window is resized right?

Comment: exactly @WesleyLachenal

Comment: Judging from the picture above, for example Bestellug, that has multiple lines. Is it really necessary? Can't it be like textarea? The design has to look that way?

Comment: unfortunately not, its got three input fileds @WesleyLachenal

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll see what I can do to give you a brief idea. Give me a few minutes. You might as well wait for the other guys to give you an answer if ever. :)

Comment: thanks man, gonna wait ;)

Comment: Can I suggest using labels for all your checkboxes to improve user experience?  `<input type="checkbox" class="begin1" id="rnd"><label for="rnd">R&D</label>` as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requirement is the form should take size of the window, using a html table for layout and column percent size could be used.

```
<div style='min-width: 800px'>
    <table style='width: 100%'>
      <tr>
        <td style='width: 25%;'><input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;Checkbox 1</td>
        <td style='width: 25%;'><input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;Checkbox 2</td>
        <td style='width: 25%;'><input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;Checkbox 3</td>
        <td style='width: 25%;'><input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;Checkbox 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table style='width: 100%'>
      <tr>
        <td style='width: 100px; min-width: 100px;'>Label&nbsp;1: </td>
        <td style='width: 50%; border-bottom: solid 1px black;'></td>
        <td style='width: 100px; min-width: 100px; padding-left: 20px;'>Label&nbsp;2: </td>
        <td style='width: 50%; border-bottom: solid 1px black'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

A new notes:

- min-width is used to prevent too small width and wrapping of elements
- table is 100% in width to fill the whole page